# Error while compiling macro __COPYRIGHT with gcc

Tags: gcc, macros

Here is the simple echo.c source code:

```
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#ifndef lint
__COPYRIGHT(
"@(#) Copyright (c) 1989, 1993\n\
    The Regents of the University of California.  All rights reserved.\n");
#endif /* not lint */

#ifndef lint
#if 0
static char sccsid[] = "@(#)echo.c  8.1 (Berkeley) 5/31/93";
#else
__RCSID("$NetBSD: echo.c,v 1.7 1997/07/20 06:07:03 thorpej Exp $");
#endif
#endif /* not lint */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main __P((int, char *[]));

int
main(argc, argv)
    int argc;
    char *argv[];
{
    /*
     *main code with no error at all
     */
}
```

When compiling it with gcc 4.4.6, it report errors:

```
echo.c:4: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before string constant
echo.c:3: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
echo.c:12: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before string constant
echo.c:12: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
```

Line 3 and 4 is __COPYRIGHT macro.
Line 12 is __RCSID macro.

If I delete these two macro, it compiles successfully and runs correctly.

After some googling, I know that these two macros are defined in sys/cdefs.h and they are some kind of comment message.

But why it won't compile in gcc?

Answer (score 2):

Well after going throuhg sys/cdefs.h (ubuntu 11.10), I found no `__COPYRIGHT` or `__RCSID` defination.
So I guess these two macros are defined in NetBSD sys/cdefs.h.
I added them in a new header file (I name it with "aeodefs.h") like the following:

```
#ifndef _AEODEFS_H_
#define _AEODEFS_H_
#include <sys/cdefs.h>

#define __IDSTRING(name,string) \
        static const char name[] __attribute__((__unused__)) = string

#ifndef __RCSID
#define __RCSID(s) __IDSTRING(rcsid,s)
#endif

#ifndef __COPYRIGHT
#define __COPYRIGHT(s) __IDSTRING(copyright,s)
#endif

#endif /* !_AEODEFS_H_ */
```

Then change `#include <sys/cdefs.h>` to `#include "aeodefs.h"`.

It's done!